# How to change comment type in PhpStorm

Tags: ide, phpstorm, comments, webstorm

Currently in my `css` files using the keyboard shortcut for a comment it will apply a comment with `//`.

However I would like to use a comment style like so `/* comment */`

Are you able to change this in PhpStorm/WebStorm?

Comment: `//` is not valid as comment symbol in plain `.css` files -- IDE uses correct `/* */` style here. Maybe you are using PostCSS where `//` is a valid for comments?

Comment: If IDE actually uses `//` for comments in `*.css` files then check what CSS Dialect is set in `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Stylesheets | Dialects` -- must be PostCSS. Another possibility -- `*.css` files (or that particular file) is associated with some another File Type (e.g. PostCSS).

Comment: In any case: You may force `/* */` for comments even for PostCSS -- use `Block Comment` shortcut instead of just `Comment`. You will have to make a selection first though...

Comment: Indeed I am using postcss guys, but I'd rather not use these comments. I will check these shortcuts, thanks LazyOne!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`//` is not valid as comment symbol in plain CSS files. The IDE uses correct `/* */` style here.

If the IDE actually uses that for comments in CSS files then check what CSS Dialect is set in `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Stylesheets | Dialects`. It sounds like it may set it to **PostCSS** (where `//` is valid).

Another possibility: `*.css` files are associated with some other File Type (e.g. already mentioned PostCSS or perhaps Less/Sass).

---

**In any case:** you may force `/* */` for comments even for PostCSS: just use the `Block Comment` shortcut instead of just `Comment`. *You will have to make a selection first though...*

`Code | Comment with Block Comment` (<kbd>Ctrl + Shift + /</kbd> using most keymaps).

Comment: I wonder about the comment that `//` is valid in `postcss`. Is it? I use postcss and it doesn't remove/convert `//` in the output. What am I missing?

Comment: @DavidGilbertson Sorry, not using PostCSS myself so cannot comment on that. But maybe you have some plugin / config for that? https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-comment or https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-strip-inline-comments etc..

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may indeed be the Project CSS Dialect. would love to see an option to force comment style to /* */

Not sure if // is valid, because i'm getting total crashes when using them (and it's so annoying when you toggle something temporary)

The block comment shortcut `cmnd + shift + /` is also toggling the help menu of macOS which is annoying.

You can upvote the problem to JetBrains here:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31121/Invalid-PostCSS-comments

so please do so the team can patch this for a next release in the future

Comment: You can disable the toggling of the MacOS help menu if you wish, it is a keyboard shortcut defined in MacOS itself. Sys Prefs > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > App Shortcuts > All Applications > Show Help Menu (by default it is ⇧⌘/) 

Comment: Thanks!, [https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31121](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31121) they added this feature in PHPstorm in the upcoming release, so it will be fixed :)

Comment: The problem is indeed fixed, i'm testing it currently in the php 2023.1 RC